# Trigger Enter Keyup/Keydown/Keypress on a Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, automation

I am trying to automate a a website where you type a number into a textbox and then when you click enter on the keyboard it goes to the next page. However the script I wrote to do this returns true, but it never goes to the next page. I can't tell if it is actually firing or not or what is happening.

HTML of textbox:

```
<input name="LegalId" id="gs_LegalId" style="padding: 0px; width: 100%;" type="text" value=""></input>
```

Javascript script:

```
function os_RaiseEnterEvent(eventname,elementId)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var event;
if(document.createEvent)
{
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent(eventname, true, false);

    if(eventname == "keydown" || eventname == "keyup")
    {
        event.keyCode = 13;
    }
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
else if(document.createEventObject)
{
    event = document.createEventObject();
    if(eventname == "keydown" || eventname == "keyup")
    {
        event.keyCode = 13;
    }
    element.fireEvent("on" + eventname, event);
}
return true;
}
```

I am invoking it by: `os_RaiseEnterEvent("keydown", "gs_LegalId:)`

Comment: did HTML let you off with mistakenly writing "intput" rather than "input" for your input tag?.

Comment: that was just me typo'd when i typed it into the question. I didn't write the website. Fixing it now.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. Why aren't you just adding keyup and other events on the text box using addEventListener()? It looks to me like you're creating a custom event but I'm not sure why you're doing that in this case.

Comment: If you can't tell if things are firing (aka going into conditionals), use a debugger to follow the script. If you can't, console.log to the rescue.